# RestSharp (C#) - Deserialize JSON Objects to NULL

Tags: c#, json, serialization, restsharp

I'm trying to understand REST by utilizing RestSharp in my application.

Here is a bit of JSON that my client is returning:

```
{
   "result" : {
      "object_type" : "session",
      "user_id" : "FEE3CBD4-5D35-11E3-A42A-606A40E381E5",
      "object_name" : "Session",
      "id" : "2F2968B6-5D37-11E3-89F4-5D6A40E381E5"
   }
}
```

Here is my class object:

```
public class TGCResult : IDeserializer
{
    public string object_type {get; set;}
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string object_name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }

    public TGCResult()
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "object_type = " + object_type + "\nuser_id = " + user_id + "\nobject_name = " + object_name + "\nid = " + id;
    }
}
```

And here is the code in which I am retrieving the JSON and attempting to deserialize:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.xxxxxxxxx.com");

var request = new RestRequest("/api/session", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("username", "JSventoraGD");
request.AddParameter("password", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
request.AddParameter("api_key_id", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<TGCResult>(request, response =>
{
    TxtTest.Text = response.Data.ToString();
});

asyncHandle.Abort();
```

When doing this, I can see the data is returned to my application correctly, but the Data in my response always has NULL values. Any ideas on why this might be happening? Am I supposed to manually deserialize the JSON given the content? The samples I've seen online have a very similar setup to mine, I'm lost... any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
var asyncHandle=client.ExecuteAsync(request,response=>{    
   String res=response.Content;
   T obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(res); 
});
```

Comment: Please, detail better your answer

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
request.RootElement = "result";
```

I have just spent a couple of hours trying to get a simple GET request to parse anything but null, setting RootElement helped me. Bit surprised i needed it since you set your type class several other places in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using it like this

```
var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync(request, response =>
{
    var json = response.Content;
    // deserialize to TGCResult
});
```

This works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to have another class as your Data type.

```
public class TGCResultContainer
{
    public TGCResult result { get; set; }
}
```

Also, your TGCResult class does not need to implement IDeserializer.